# Should code be rewritten or should I use methods?

Tags: c#, performance

First of all, I couldn't find this question, so I decided to post here.

While working on a game, I realized the more entities I have on the playing field, the more the fps drops, which is expected.

To optimize it, I read somewhere (I'll post the link if I can find it) that if you rewrite code instead of using universal methods, it is faster, because it doesn't have to 'link' the methods each time it runs the code. But, since I am rewriting code, It might take up some more virtual space.

I just want to know your opinions on this, and if you think it is true.
And I would gladly accept any other optimization tactics or links.

**Edit:** *What's the point of making the question 'too broad' after the answer is selected? If the answer was selected it means there was a valid answer, which means that the question was not too broad, otherwise the answerneers would have had problems...*

Thanks

Comment: Rewriting could just make it worse, just try to see if you can refactor your code to be more efficient, less loops if possible

Comment: To the person who -1'ed: Thanks for -1'ing, it really helps.
@Sayse Well, I'm going to have loops, a lot of them actually, because I have to process entities on the playing field (only the ones that are on the screen, atm). I'll try to refactor and see if that helps.

Comment: What I did in a similar project was to define an interface that all my different entities could use then all their updates could be done from one loop `foreach(IInterface obj in myObjs) obj.Update()`

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference other than making your code harder to follow and maintain/extend.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:opengl]? Isn't XNA DirectX only?

Comment: I would be very surprised if function calls are causing your performance problem.  Use a profiler to find out what is.  Use both CPU and GPU profilers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than trying to guess what is hogging the CPU in your app you should consider profiling the performance characteristics of your app. This can help you home in on the parts of your code that are consuming most CPU time. Find the most CPU intensive part of your code, make adjustments that you believe will improve the performance of that code and then run the performance analyzers again. Once you make a change it would not be unusual for the performance characteristics reported by the analyzer to change considerably. If you can't optimize the heaviest part any more then move on to the next heaviest part.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, back in the days when you had a single core CPU, that ran at 100Mhz, then the overhead involved in looking up a function call and jumping to that memory location to run the method and then jumping back on completion added up - especially when you had a lot of little methods, or a single method that was called a lot.

So they invented inlining for compilers, which automatically optimised your code by copying such little functions directly into your code - so you get the benefit of writing methods, and the compiler fixes things up so it still performed like you'd written it all out using one big method.

But that was then, today, when you have 8 core phones running at several Ghz and pipelining and heavily optimising compilers, the cost of method calls is insignificant. You will have other problems that cause performance issues. You will.

today the most common cause is memory copying, because the CPU goes so fast, it needs a good steady stream of data to work with, and when you have to stop to fetch a block of memory from somewhere else, this really costs. As you're using C# the next step is to look at your object creation - just like Stringbuffer was invented to make string copying perform well, if you allocate lots and lots and lots of objects, you're going to find it goes slowly.

But still, I'm guessing - your problems could be elsewhere, so look! Find out where the perf problems are, and fix them.